# Share connection pool between multiple Jetty servers

Tags: java, jetty, share, connection-pooling

I know my question is unusual but I really need to do it.

I have multiple Web sites and services. Every site or service starts in it's own Jetty server. It is very useful for me and I don't want to refuse this architecture. Every app have 3 pooled datasources (c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource) for 3 databases. And... there are minimum 120 opened connections to my PGSQL server. And 3000 maximum =)

Is there any way to share connection pool between my applications or Jetty servers?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was suggested to me by a friend. And it is very simple =)

I should use [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer#Project_Overview).